# Sum total hours and minutes for each userprofileid with Python

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I want get the amount of `totalhours` and `totalminutes` for each `userprofileid` I have.

For example:

```
userprofileid      totalhours    totalminutes
453                7.0           420
120                7.5           450
453                8.0           480
```

I can't delete `userprofileid` because each id have their hours and minutes.

I tried this but I get total amount of hours and minutes, and add they in each row.

```
for user in clocking_left["userprofileid"]:
clocking_left["user_minutes_total"] = clocking_left["totalminutes"].sum()
clocking_left["user_hours_total"] = clocking_left["hours"].sum()
```

Comment: Use [`.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html?highlight=groupby#pandas.DataFrame.groupby)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use group by and sum up the values

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'userprofileid': [453,120,453],
        'totalhours': [7.0,7.5,8],
'totalminutes': [420,450,480]       
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['userprofileid','totalhours','totalminutes'])

df_new = df.groupby('userprofileid').sum().reset_index()

print(df_new.to_string(index=False))
```

output

```
userprofileid  totalhours  totalminutes
           120         7.5           450
           453        15.0           900
```

Comment: Hi man! Thanks for the help!
But if I want to create another column with those variables?
Can I do df["new"] = df.groupby('userprofileid').sum().reset_index()).to_string(index=False)?

Comment: You want to create a new df and not modify the existing df?

Comment: Yes, I want modify my df, but I want create another 2 columns:
work_hours and work_minutes

Comment: I have edited my answer to save the result in a new df. Please see if this is what you want

Comment: It's perfect! I realised I can't made a new column because I have less rows. Thanks man!